# Array processing in Power Query

Tags: arrays, powerquery, m

I have a table with a column array A1, A2, A3, A4,... and an index column Ind which takes the values 1,2,3,4,... I want to create a column that returns the array element using the index. I could do it with a nested if

```
     if Ind = 1 then A1
else if Ind = 2 then A2
else if Ind = 3 then A3
else if Ind = 3 then A4 ...
```

is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are A1, A2, etc. the values in column A? If so, adding a custom column with the formula `each [A]` will do what you want. If you need to get the value from a different row you can use {} to get the value at index, like `TableName[A]{Ind + 1}`. You will have to make sure that the index you are using doesn't go below 0 or greater than or equal to the number of rows. You can use an if/else statement to keep the index bounded.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. What i meant was that A1, A2 etc. are separate columns from a sql database, they are only an array implicitly. I can turn them into a list as A = {A1, A2, A3, ...}, and then use an index but I guess what I fundamentally want to do is somehow leverage the names of the columns directly.

Comment: Do the names follow a pattern? You can use `Record.Field` to get the value from the column when you add a custom column. For example, if the base name is "A", you could get the value of column A(Ind) with `Record.Field(_, "A" & Number.ToText(Ind))`.